# Microsoft Multipoint SDK not registering (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, multipoint

All the Microsoft tutorials are in C#, but I'm usually pretty good at converting between. However, I cannot solve this for the life of me. How do I convert `Multipointsdk.Instance.Register(this);` into VB.NET? My first shot was `MultipointSdk.Instance.Register(Me)` but it won't let me cast "Me" to a Window type. Code below:

```
            Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
            Imports Microsoft.Multipoint.Sdk

            Public Class Form1

                Private InitialStyle As Integer
                Dim PercentVisible As Decimal

                Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
                    InitialStyle = GetWindowLong(Me.Handle, -20)
                    PercentVisible = 0.8

                    SetWindowLong(Me.Handle, -20, InitialStyle Or &H80000 Or &H20)

                    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(Me.Handle, 0, 255 * PercentVisible, &H2)

                    Me.BackColor = Color.Red
                    Me.TopMost = True
                    MultipointSdk.Instance.Register(Me)
                End Sub

                <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetWindowLong")> Public Shared Function GetWindowLong(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer) As Integer
                End Function

                <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetWindowLong")> Public Shared Function SetWindowLong(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer, ByVal dwNewLong As Integer) As Integer
                End Function

                <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetLayeredWindowAttributes")> Public Shared Function SetLayeredWindowAttributes(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal crKey As Integer, ByVal alpha As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Integer) As Boolean
                End Function

            End Class
```

Comment: For a start, you might want to take note of the remark in [GetWindowLong](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633584(v=vs.85).aspx): "this function has been superseded by the GetWindowLongPtr function." I'm not saying that will fix it ;)

Comment: Haven't gotten there yet, but thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Also, you'll be wanting to set [`Option Strict On`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) to avoid type mismatches that could scupper your chances of getting it to work properly.

Comment: How do I convert Me into its proper type? (System.Windows.Window)

Comment: Found it, the SDK doesn't work with forms apps.

Comment: @westonsupermare , Is this SDK is applicable for Windows 2012 multipoint server ?

Comment: No, this is the old Microsoft SDK that allows the usage of multiple mouse cursors.